# Preprocessor (directive) similarity

Tags: c#, .net, c-preprocessor, directive

I'm making object initialization in more than five methods with the same name and same parameter text as following.

```
new Project.NameSpace.Method(sameTextHere);
```

Example usage in a method,

```
public AObject ExampleMethod(AObject sameTextHere)
{
    var table = new Project.NameSpace.Method(sameTextHere); // gotten AObject in table variable
    ....
    return table;
}
```

In C/C++, I can write something like `#DEFINE ATEXT "new Project.NameSpace.Method(sameTextHere)"` which replaces in compiling all `ATEXT` strings with `new Project.NameSpace.Method(sameTextHere)`.

Can the aim be done in C#? I'm aware of absence of directives in C#.

Comment: Does `using Project.NameSpace;` works for you?

Comment: Have you considered using Code Snippets to simplify/speed up inserting repeated code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-code-snippets?view=vs-2015

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski my writing is not hard to understand clearly. I need and wonder merely solely just one text replacement as showed in my question or a way similar to it.

Comment: Hi there. You could look at [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1). In short from the docs `A dependency is any object that another object requires`. This way you'll able to use it in your class as a private variable and inject it through your consturctor and access any [public] method of that class. See docs for more information. Let me know if you need more information. I'll write an answer with some examples and be more detailed.

Comment: @Scircia thank you sir. I'll let you know if I'm stuck on a point.